# Decode a base64 encoded JSON string generated from JavaScript in Python

Tags: javascript, python, json, unicode, base64

Take this base64-encoded JSON string generated from JavaScript using `JSON.stringify` and `btoa`:

```js
btoa(JSON.stringify({"é": "è"}))
"eyLpIjoi6CJ9"
```

I'm trying to decode it from Python. I'm doing:

```py
>>> import base64
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(base64.b64decode("eyLpIjoi6CJ9"))
```

I'm getting a `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 2: invalid continuation byte
```

What is the right way to properly decode this in Python?

Note: I'm using base64 encoding so this can be safely passed as an URL query string parameter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do in JavaScript

```
    btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({"é": "è"}))))
    base64 output: eyLDqSI6IsOoIn0=
```

though I think btoa works on just the extended ascii table, not all unicode characters.

Then in Python

```
    json.loads(base64.b64decode("eyLDqSI6IsOoIn0=")
    prints: {'é': 'è'}
```

Comment: btoa is latin-1 :/ https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/D%C3%A9coder_encoder_en_base64#Le_%C2%AB_probl%C3%A8me_Unicode_%C2%BB